# Created form displays as [object HTMLFormElement]

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a series of list items using template literals and constructing components within each item. Currently, I'm setting the inner `HTML` of the list item to an expression that will create a simple form component. I don't see the form however, but `[object HTMLFormElement]` is displayed instead.

My code:

```
let editListItem = document.createElement('li');
let editListForm = document.createElement('form');

function editlistItemTemp(name) {
  editListItem.classList.add('list-item-edit-view');

  editListItem.innerHTML = `
  ${editListFormTemp(name)}`;

  return editListItem;
}

function editListFormTemp(value) {
  editListForm.classList.add('edit-list-form');

  editListForm.innerHTML = `
  <input class='list-edit-input' type='text' value='${value}' placeholder='List Name' required />`;

  return editListForm;
}
```

I know that `HTMLFormElement` is the collection containing the form, but I don't know why it displays this way here. I've console logged the function `editListFormTemp()` and nothing seems out of place, as I get precisely the HTML element I'm looking for.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVZMq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `innerHtml` of returned `HTML`:

```
editListItem.innerHTML = editListFormTemp(name).innerHTML;
```

Also you can use `append` too: `editListItem.append(editListFormTemp(name))`

Here is working sample:

```js
 let editListItem = document.createElement('li');
        let editListForm = document.createElement('form');

        editlistItemTemp("text");

        function editlistItemTemp(name) {
            editListItem.classList.add('list-item-edit-view');

            editListItem.innerHTML = editListFormTemp(name).innerHTML;

            document.body.append(editListItem)

            return editListItem;
        }

        function editListFormTemp(value) {
            editListForm.classList.add('edit-list-form');

            editListForm.innerHTML = `<input class='list-edit-input' type='text' value='${value}' placeholder='List Name' required />`;

            return editListForm;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, and this makes a lot of sense. I guess cause innerHTML is getting stacked in a sense, I need to use the `innerHTML` property on the thing I want returned.